# How to bind array values in dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am having this array

```
 var serviceArray= new Array("Living Room","Dining Room","Bedroom(s)","Family Room","Kitchen","Den","Hallway(s)","Ste(s)","Bathroom","Landing(s)");
```

I want to bind all this array values in option of following select tag using jquery..

```
    <select class="services_list"></select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bind"? Do you want to create `option` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaxtkmo8/)

#### HTML:

```
<select class="services_list"></select>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var serviceArray= new Array("Living Room","Dining Room","Bedroom(s)","Family Room","Kitchen","Den","Hallway(s)","Ste(s)","Bathroom","Landing(s)");

for (i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
    var data = '<option>' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>'
    $('select').append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your array and append option to your select element.

*Heres Example:*

```js
var serviceArray = new Array("Living Room", "Dining Room", "Bedroom(s)", "Family Room", "Kitchen", "Den", "Hallway(s)", "Ste(s)", "Bathroom", "Landing(s)");

$(document).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
    $('.services_list').append('<option>' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="services_list"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to create a select option list with the array so you can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
var serviceArray= new Array("Living Room","Dining Room","Bedroom(s)","Family Room","Kitchen","Den","Hallway(s)","Ste(s)","Bathroom","Landing(s)");
$(serviceArray).each(function(){
    $('<option>'+this+'</option>').appendTo('.services_list');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b799b1wz/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    var options = '';
    var serviceArray= new Array("Living Room","Dining Room","Bedroom(s)","Family Room","Kitchen","Den","Hallway(s)","Ste(s)","Bathroom","Landing(s)");
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceArray.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + serviceArray[i] + '">' + serviceArray[i] + '</option>';
    }
    $('.services_list').html(options);
```

Comment: Performance wise generating string and then using `html()` is better.